# Asp.Net Identity Creating role in seed method failed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roles, asp.net-identity

I tried to add a new role in the seed method, but when i run the code, the browser keep loading and have no response. Using the debugger, it was found that the code hanged on the create method.

I have no idea what's going.. Any help is appreciated .

Thanks !

```
public class ApplicationDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<ApplicationDbContext> 
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
            new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
        var idResult = rm.Create(new IdentityRole("Admin"));

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Global.asax file:

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbContextInitializer());

        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        db.Users.FirstOrDefault();

    }
}
```

Following this article, Seeding data is fine with migration. But i would like to find a solution without using migration so that it will drop and create a new database everytime the model changes.
http://typecastexception.com/post/2013/11/11/Extending-Identity-Accounts-and-Implementing-Role-Based-Authentication-in-ASPNET-MVC-5.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing

```
var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
    new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

to use the context that was passed into the `Seed()` method, rather than creating a new one...

```
var rm = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(
    new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
```